# How to select a row with column1=<fixed value> and column2 is the max value in it?

Tags: sql

I have a table like:

```
|pj|scan|time|
+--+----+----+
| 1|6000|  1 |
| 2|7000|  2 |
| 2|8000|  3 |
| 3|9000|  4 |
```

I want to query the row with max time around id=2, so the result should be:

```
| 2|8000|  3 |
```

How can I do it?

Comment: what is your dbms?

Comment: postgresql with sqlalchemy

Answer (score 1):

Try any of this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME
WHERE pj=2
ORDER BY time DESC
LIMIT 1;


SELECT TOP 1 * FROM TABLENAME
WHERE pj=2
ORDER BY time DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below -

```
select * from
(
select * , row_number() over(partition by pj order by scan desc) as rn
from t where pj=2
)A where rn=1
```